# Bootstrap 3 col-xs not working as expected

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using Bootstrap 3 for a *fairly* simple table, I need to display 4 columns side by side even on phones, something like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" >
    <div class="col-xs-5" >
      <p style="margin-top: 25%;">A Day in the life of Dror</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">6:30 am<br />7:30 am<br />8:00 am<br />13:00 am<br />16:00 am<br />17:00 am<br />18:00 am<br />20:00 am<br />22:00 am<br />23:00 am</div>
    <div class="col-xs-1">sample img</div>
    <div class="col-xs-5 ">WAKE UP <br />MEETING / BREAKFAST <br />FIRST LESSON / TFILA <br />LUNCH BREAK <br />END OF SCHOOL <br />HOMEWORK TIME<br />DINNER <br />EXTRA CURRICULUM ACTIVITIES<br />ALL RETURN TO BUILDING <br />LIGHT'S OUT</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

but on phones it still displays stacked.

Comment: Have you made sure that the dependencies are correctly loaded?

Comment: @Sidharth i have... bootstrap works fine on all the website

Comment: Try to display in table formate

Comment: It's working properly.

Comment: Ok, What is the resolution you're testing?

Comment: Could be a version issue. Bootstrap 3 allows col-xs, but I believe bootstrap 4 does col-12 for example.

Comment: This is table data, use tables! Or at least set `white-space: nowrap;` on some parent or you will face issues with text wrapping and lines not matching...

Comment: @YejielIMP Check my ans may be its work for u :)

Answer (score 0):

Well the code works fine, you must be facing an issue due the padding on smaller phones, maybe you can set the padding to `0px` or to any other value less than the default which is `15px` for both the left and right side, we need to do this  for all the columns under the row.

```
.remove-padding > div{
  padding:0px;
}
```

So I add the class `remove-padding` to the remove the padding for all the children of the first level of row (i.e the columns under the row). Please let me know if this fixes your issue.

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

Comment: @YejielIMP If you resize the JSfiddle window right it does not collapse, can you recreate the issue in the JSFiddle and share back?

Answer (score 0):

```css
.table {
    border-bottom:0px !important;
}
.table th, .table td {
    border: 1px !important;
}
.fixed-table-container {
    border:0px !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="margin-top:50px";>

<div class="container">
   <table class="table">
  
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td> </td>
        <td>6:30 am</td>
        <td>sample img</td>
        <td>WAKE UP</td>
      </tr>
      
      <tr>
        <td> </td>
        <td>7:30 am</td>
        <td> </td>
        <td>MEETING / BREAKFAST</td>
      </tr>
      
      <tr>
        <td> </td>
        <td>8:00 am</td>
        <td> </td>
        <td>FIRST LESSON / TFILA </td>
      </tr>
      
       <tr>
        <td> </td>
        <td>13:00 am</td>
        <td> </td>
        <td>LUNCH BREAK</td>
      </tr>
      
       <tr>
        <td> A Day in the life of Dror </td>
        <td>16:00 am</td>
        <td> </td>
        <td>END OF SCHOOL</td>
      </tr>
     
       <tr>
        <td> </td>
        <td>17:00 am</td>
        <td> </td>
        <td>HOMEWORK TIME</td>
      </tr>

       <tr>
        <td> </td>
        <td>18:00 am</td>
        <td> </td>
        <td>DINNER</td>
      </tr>
  
       <tr>
        <td> </td>
        <td>20:00 am</td>
        <td> </td>
        <td>EXTRA CURRICULUM ACTIVITIES</td>
      </tr>
       
   <tr>
        <td> </td>
        <td>23:00 am</td>
        <td> </td>
        <td>ALL RETURN TO BUILDING</td>
      </tr>
      
       <tr>
        <td> </td>
        <td>24:00 am</td>
        <td> </td>
        <td>LIGHT'S OUT</td>
      </tr>
      
  </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```